# Android: automatically execute the Gallery widget to slide to the next image?

Tags: android

Essentially, I want the Gallery to switch images automatically based on a timer. So, after 10 seconds I would like a method to execute an image switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a `TimerTask` with

```
run()
{
    gallery.setSelection(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks. But is there any method to have it slide rather than switch immediately?

Comment: For that use a viewFlipper insted of gallery because ShowNext() and showPrevious methods of view Flipper will slide with inAnimaion and outManimation which you can define at urself also . in case  you bounded to use Gallery then search for setting In animation/out animation during sliding . i think its possible .